# Script run at startup is not logging output

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, startup

I've been trying to run the following code at startup on a Raspberry Pi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy
import math
import cv2
#this is python 3 specific
import urllib.request
from enum import Enum
from VisionProcessor import VisionProcessor
from GripPipeline import GripPipeline
from networktables import NetworkTables
import time
import logging
from networktables.util import ntproperty

#proper networktables setup
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
NetworkTables.initialize(server='10.17.11.76')

#create the field to talk to on the network table
class NTClient(object):
    angle_difference = ntproperty('/Raspberry Pi/angle difference', 0)
    distance_from_target = ntproperty('/Raspberry Pi/distance from target', 0)

n = NTClient()

frame = cv2.VideoCapture('https://frc:frc@10.17.11.11/mjpg/video.mjpg')

if(frame == None):
    print("error: camera not found. check connection")
#pipeline = GripPipeline()
pipeline = VisionProcessor()


print("pipeline created")

def get_image():
    ret, img_array = frame.read()
#    cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", img_array)
    return img_array

def find_distance(width, height, y):
    #distances are in inches
    KNOWN_WIDTH = 6.25
    KNOWN_DISTANCE = 12.0
    KNOWN_PIXELS = 135.5
    KNOWN_HEIGHT = 424.0

    focal_length = (KNOWN_PIXELS * KNOWN_DISTANCE)/KNOWN_WIDTH
    #hypotenuse = (KNOWN_WIDTH * focal_length)/width
    distance = (KNOWN_WIDTH * focal_length)/width

    #0.2125 degrees per pixel vertical
#    theta = (0.2125) * (240 - y)

#    distance = KNOWN_HEIGHT * (math.tan((math.pi / 2) - math.radians(theta)))

    return distance

x = True
while x:
    print("while loop entered")
    img = get_image()
    print("image gotten")
    center_point = [160, 120]
    file = open('output.txt', 'a')
    try:
        current_point, size, y = pipeline.process(img)
        #negative means turn left, positive means turn right
        pixel_difference = center_point[0] - current_point[0]
        #4.7761 pixels per degree
        angle_difference = (float)(pixel_difference) / 4.7761
        n.angle_difference = angle_difference
        target_width = size[0]
        target_height = size[1]
        distance = find_distance(target_width, target_height, y)
        n.distance_from_target = distance
        print("angle")
        file.write("angle: ")
        print(n.angle_difference)
        file.write(str(angle_difference))
        print(" distance: ")
        file.write("distance")
        print(distance)
        file.write(str(distance))
        file.write("\n")
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print(":(")
    except (TypeError, cv2.error) as e:
        print(":(")

#    x = False
```

I've been doing this by editing the `/etc/rc.local` file, and the script has been running "successfully". The Pi shows ~25% CPU usage upon startup, and it remains consistent while the script is running, so I can see when it is active (I'm not running any other processes on this Pi). Using `ps -aux` shows the active python3 process. However, it's not outputting anything, either to the `output.txt` file or to the networktables.

My end goal is to get it to output successfully to the networktable. If I run it normally (e.g. not at startup, via `python3 pipeline-test.py` in the terminal), it correctly outputs to both `output.txt` and the networktable. I added `output.txt` as a way to ensure that I'm getting correct output, and it's working just fine except when it's run at startup.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong? If any more info is needed, I can do my best to provide it.

EDIT: for some reason, when I copied my code over from Github, it lost all the indentation. The code in use is [here](https://github.com/RaptorsYellowLaptop/vision-processing/blob/master/pipeline-test.py).

Comment: It would help if the code in question was indented properly.

Comment: @martineau Yeah sorry, I copied it out of my Github and for some reason the indentation didn't carry over. I've fixed it. The indentation is correct where it's being run.

Comment: Why is your `open` statement inside your loop? You are opening the file over and over. It should be outside the loop and probably you should look at using the `with open`..." pattern. Also your indent is still off... your excepts need to be the same level as your try.

Comment: @RobertB I moved the open statement, it was originally put there when I was running the loop only once and wanted to catch any potential file exceptions. I forgot to move it back out when I set x back to True. However, it is still failing. (Also, I linked to the actual code from Github which has the proper indentation)

Comment: Not familiar with Raspberry Pi or vision processing :(. However, it sounds permissions related. When the rc.local comnands are executed, who is the "user" and what is the "current working directory"? Does your process have write permissions in that cwd? Is the file being created but placed somewhere unexpected? What about putting an absolute path n your `open` - maybe to `/tmp` or something?

Comment: @RobertB The file isn't being created, it already exists and the 'a' designation notes that the script should append to it. I set the permissions of the script itself to `chmod 755`, but it still isn't working. `output.txt` is in the same directory as the script.

Comment: Since the `open('output.txt', 'a')`—wherever the statement is located—doesn't specify a path it will always append to (or create) the file in whatever the cwd (current working directory) happens to be when the script is run. One way to correct that would be by supplying a fully qualified path to the file. Another might be to have the script change the cwd to be the directory in which the file is located.

Comment: @martineau I tried adding the full path '/home/pi/python/output.txt' but then it didn't print anything to the file, even when run normally. Is there a different way I should format the full path name? I couldn't find any specific information on that.

Comment: @martineau the command is being run with `sudo` in `rc.local`

Comment: That looks like the proper way to specify the path to the file. Are you saying that neither the `print` nor `file.write` calls worked (and no errors are occurring)?

Comment: The `print` calls are working correctly and printing info to the terminal, however when using the full pathname, nothing is being output to the file.

Comment: @martineau When I moved the file back into the loop, the full pathname works to write to the file

Comment: So the problem's solved?

Comment: @martineau Unfortunately no, it still fails when run at startup. However, it works when running it normally now.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a permissions problem to me. There should be a way to specify what permissions a script has when run at startup. I don't know enough about such things on Linux to help. Sorry.

Comment: rc.local is run after network script, but network needs some time to be available. So you can add a sleep in rc.local, for instance: `(sleep 60; python3 /path_to/pipeline-test.py)&`. Note: `/etc/rc.local` is run by root.

Comment: @ArnoBozo Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the /etc/rc.local script executes as root, thus in the root directory. You will need to add the full file path to your python program. This may or may not solve the issue.

```
python /dir/dir/python_program
```

You can record the output of this program in an error file. Make the file

```
sudo nano /home/pi/error.log
```

In that file, just type anything, and exit (ctrl + x) saving the changes. Then you edit the rc.local so that the messages are appended to the file

```
python /dir/dir/python_program > /home/pi/error.log &
```

now perform a reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

the pi will boot, and run the program, after a few minutes, pkill python and view the /home/pi/error.log file. This will give you a better idea of what's going on with your programs "Fail state"

I notice in your program you call a file. rather than output.txt, you will need the full path to the file, since the program is executed in the root directory at startup. this will need to be changed in all instances where your program calls any file.

if you then get a permissions error in the log file, run the following

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /filepath_to_your_script
```